# Next's page.tsx export force-dynamic does not render dynamically

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a page that I want to render dynamically and not statically. Unfortunately the universal answer of simply doing:

```js
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

does not work.
I've also tried

```js
export const revalidate = 0;
```

and I've tried many combinations of those.

I know that it's being rendered statically because the client is not making any request to the server for 5 minutes after the page is visited, as is normal for statically rendered pages.

Another weird aspect is that I am using the cookie to do a fetch. No `cache` argument is specified for the fetch.

The page's path is `/reports/income-statement`, so it is not using slugs. Does that mean I can't force it to be dynamic?
I'm also not using any searchParams (though it does accept searchParams).

Version: Tried with both Next 13.4.5 and 13.4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I've found the answer to my problem: The Next 13 docs are wrong, or at least VERY misleading.

When it comes to the Router Cache, you cannot configure a Page to be dynamic or not. Declarations like export `const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'` or `export const dynamic = 'auto'` are not respected for Pages. Likewise, the cache options for your `fetch` requests do not matter.

Source: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/54075

The only ways to affect the Router Cache are to use Server Actions OR to use router.refresh().